# Файл js выдаёт ошибку, но если напрямую генерить код из этого файла в html, то всё работает

Tags: javascript, html

Опишу вкратце суть проблемы. Это код js файла, и среда указывает на две ошибки. 5 и 9 строка. Содержание ошибки: ожидалось выражение. Дело в том, что если этот скрипт писать напрямую в HTML файл, куда мне нужно, то скрипт работает. А если оформлять данный скрипт в отдельный файл и подключать его с помощью , то скрипт не работает. В js начал недавно разбираться, и хочу узнать в чём ошибка в файле. Ну, вдобавок, очень не хочется писать громоздкий код напрямую в файл html, а подключить скрипт извне.Укажите, пожалуйста, в чём суть ошибки и как её можно исправить.

```
    <script>
      startdate = new Date();
      clockStart = startdate.getTime();
      function initStopwatch() {
        var thisTime = new Date(); 
        return (thisTime.getTime() - clockStart)/1000; 
      }
      function getSecs() {
        var tSecs = Math.round(initStopwatch());
        var iSecs = tSecs % 60;
        var iMins = Math.round((tSecs-30)/60);
        var sSecs ="" + ((iSecs > 9) ? iSecs : "0" + iSecs);
        var sMins ="" + ((iMins > 9) ? iMins : "0" + iMins);
        document.getElementById("timer-counter").innerHTML = sMins+":"+sSecs;
        setTimeout('getSecs()', 1000); 
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: **var** startdate = ...; **var** clockStart = ...; - возможно, проблема и не в этом, но глаза режет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте угадаю, в html скрипт ставите после элемента timer-counter, а файл подключаете в шапке?

Работа с DOM-элементами должна происходить после загрузки всего html, потому что нельзя взять элемент, если он еще не создан. Поэтому ждите события:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    getSecs();
});
```

или так, если используете jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getSecs();
});
```

Если это единственная вызываемая функция, то можно сократить до:

```
$(document).ready(getSecs);
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!